# Java openGL draw texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures, draw, lwjgl

I try to draw a basic texture in LWJGL, but I can't.

My main class:

```
package worldofportals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.*;
import worldofportals.texture.TextureLoader;

/**
 * Initialize the program, handle the rendering, updating, the mouse and the
 * keyboard events.
 *
 * @author Laxika
 */
public class WorldOfPortals {

    /**
     * Time at the last frame.
     */
    private long lastFrame;
    /**
     * Frames per second.
     */
    private int fps;
    /**
     * Last FPS time.
     */
    private long lastFPS;
    public static final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 1024;
    public static final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 768;
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WorldOfPortals.class.getName());
    int tileId = 0;

    static {
        try {
            LOGGER.addHandler(new FileHandler("errors.log", true));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, ex.toString(), ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorldOfPortals main = null;
        try {
            main = new WorldOfPortals();
            main.create();
            main.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString(), ex);
        } finally {
            if (main != null) {
                main.destroy();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new lwjgl frame.
     *
     * @throws LWJGLException
     */
    public void create() throws LWJGLException {
        //Display
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT));
        Display.setFullscreen(false);
        Display.setTitle("World of Portals FPS: 0");
        Display.create();

        //Keyboard
        Keyboard.create();

        //Mouse
        Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
        Mouse.create();

        //OpenGL
        initGL();
        resizeGL();

        getDelta(); // call once before loop to initialise lastFrame
        lastFPS = getTime();

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable texturing
        tileId = TextureLoader.getInstance().loadTexture("img/tile1.png");
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the game.
     */
    public void destroy() {
        //Methods already check if created before destroying.
        Mouse.destroy();
        Keyboard.destroy();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the GL.
     */
    public void initGL() {
        //2D Initialization
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the keyboard events.
     */
    public void processKeyboard() {
    }

    /**
     * Handle the mouse events.
     */
    public void processMouse() {
    }

    /**
     * Handle the rendering.
     */
    public void render() {
        glPushMatrix();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            for (int j = 30; j >= 0; j--) {  // Changed loop condition here.
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tileId);
                // translate to the right location and prepare to draw
                GL11.glTranslatef(20, 20, 0);
                GL11.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

                // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
                GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                {
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                    GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 64);
                    GL11.glVertex2f(0, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(64, 64);
                    GL11.glVertex2f(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
                    GL11.glTexCoord2f(64, 0);
                    GL11.glVertex2f(DISPLAY_WIDTH, 0);
                }
                GL11.glEnd();
            }
        }

        // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

    /**
     * Resize the GL.
     */
    public void resizeGL() {
        //2D Scene
        glViewport(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0.0f, DISPLAY_WIDTH, 0.0f, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        glPushMatrix();

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glPushMatrix();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            if (Display.isVisible()) {
                processKeyboard();
                processMouse();

                update(getDelta());
                render();
            } else {
                if (Display.isDirty()) {
                    render();
                }
            }
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Game update before render.
     */
    public void update(int delta) {
        updateFPS();
    }

    /**
     * Get the time in milliseconds
     *
     * @return The system time in milliseconds
     */
    public long getTime() {
        return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate how many milliseconds have passed since last frame.
     *
     * @return milliseconds passed since last frame
     */
    public int getDelta() {
        long time = getTime();
        int delta = (int) (time - lastFrame);
        lastFrame = time;

        return delta;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the FPS and set it in the title bar
     */
    public void updateFPS() {
        if (getTime() - lastFPS > 1000) {
            Display.setTitle("World of Portals FPS: " + fps);
            fps = 0;
            lastFPS += 1000;
        }
        fps++;
    }
}
```

And my texture loader:

```
package worldofportals.texture;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;

public class TextureLoader {

    private static final int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;//3 for RGB, 4 for RGBA
    private static TextureLoader instance;

    private TextureLoader() {
    }

    public static TextureLoader getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TextureLoader();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Load a texture from file.
     * 
     * @param loc the location of the file
     * @return the id of the texture
     */
    public int loadTexture(String loc) {
        BufferedImage image = loadImage(loc);
        int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

        ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL); //4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
                buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
            }
        }

        buffer.flip();

        int textureID = glGenTextures(); //Generate texture ID
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); //Bind texture ID

        //Setup wrap mode
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        //Setup texture scaling filtering
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        //Send texel data to OpenGL
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        //Return the texture ID so we can bind it later again
        return textureID;
    }

    /**
     * Load an image from disc.
     * 
     * @param loc the location of the image
     * @return the image
     */
    private BufferedImage loadImage(String loc) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(loc));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It's not an actual game, just a test to learn and practice openGL in java. Also anyone can suggest me a good book on OpenGL?

Comment: Please be more descriptive of what your actual problem is.

Comment: I try to render something with the render() method, but nothing change, and I don't know why.

Comment: Does your code work without binding a texture? That is, can you render a flat colored primitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
    BufferedImage image = loadImage(loc);
    image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * 4);
    Color c;

    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
            buffer.put((byte) c.getRed());     // Red component
            buffer.put((byte) c.getGreen());      // Green component
            buffer.put((byte) c.getBlue());               // Blue component
            buffer.put((byte) c.getAlpha());    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
        }
    }
```

Also, if you are going to put the Alpha component, you should either check the number of components, and add the alpha only if there is 4, or ALWAYS use 4. Also, do GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGBA8.

Comment: Thanks! Replacing the loading code with yours is helped. Now it's working fine. :) Upwoted Simak's one too, swapbuffers was needed too.

Comment: Try the slick library LWJGL provides. It is much simpler than using the byte buffers..

Answer (score 3):

shouldn't you be calling the 
Display.swapBuffers() after render?

Comment: That's what I was wondering, but since I'm not familiar with this LWJGL thing, I wasn't sure if Display.update does that already :/

Comment: True, i see another problem, your texture coordinate shouldn't go from 0 to 64, but from 0 to 1